# IPhone: too much disk space is used for unknown reason

Tags: ios, iphone, disk-space

Here is a full list of all applications installed on the device:

[image]

I have already used Battery Doctor (and other apps) and cleaned cache. So what is 7.2 gb used for? How can i clean it?

I don't know if it can help but the phone was already in use before.

**Update:** Settings -> General -> About screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that iOS is taking some space since it says the capacity is 12GB even though (I'm guessing) your device is 16GB.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @tiktak I have updated my answer

Comment: Yes, but it's unclear what 7.2gb is consumed for.

Comment: @tiktak What I mean is iOS takes up that space. Remember if you update your iDevice without iTunes you need 5GB free to update. This is what is happening. the Operating System (iOS) is taking up the space. That is what I think anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit black magic - but after a wired sync with iTunes there's always some extra space freed up.

I suppose this does some extra cleaning tasks the iDevice won't do by itself.